# PHP array of Strings into int

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with some string values

```
array(4) { 
[0]=> array(2) { ["x"]=> string(13) "1475269218000" ["y"]=> string(1) "1" } 
[1]=> array(2) { ["x"]=> string(13) "1475269222000" ["y"]=> string(1) "1" } 
[2]=> array(2) { ["x"]=> string(13) "1475269231000" ["y"]=> string(1) "1" } 
[3]=> array(2) { ["x"]=> string(13) "1475269241000" ["y"]=> string(1) "1" } 
}
```

I need an output with only values as ints. So this would be the output.

```
[
[1475269218000,1],
[1475269222000,1],
[1475269231000,1]
[1475269241000,1]
]
```

Comment: You should be able to loop thru the arrays using foreach() and rebuild the output. Cast the values as (int).

Comment: you can use array_values() function

Comment: 64bit system I hope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

```
$ar = [
    ['x' => '1475269218000', 'y' => '1'],
    ['x' => '1475269222000', 'y' => '1'],
    ['x' => '1475269231000', 'y' => '1'],
    ['x' => '1475269241000', 'y' => '1']
];

foreach($ar AS $key1 => $sub_ars) {
    foreach($sub_ars AS $key2 => $val) {
        $ar[$key1][$key2] = intval($val);
    }
}
var_dump($ar);
```

Option 2:

```
$ar = [
    ['x' => '1475269218000', 'y' => '1'],
    ['x' => '1475269222000', 'y' => '1'],
    ['x' => '1475269231000', 'y' => '1'],
    ['x' => '1475269241000', 'y' => '1']
];

function intvalRecursive($val)
{
    if(is_array($val)) {
        return array_map('intvalRecursive', $val);
    }
    return intval($val);
}

$ar = array_map('intvalRecursive', $ar);
var_dump($ar);
```

Option 3 (stripping keys):

```
$ar = [
    ['x' => '1475269218000', 'y' => '1'],
    ['x' => '1475269222000', 'y' => '1'],
    ['x' => '1475269231000', 'y' => '1'],
    ['x' => '1475269241000', 'y' => '1']
];

foreach($ar AS $key => $val) {
    $ar[$key] = array_values(array_map('intval', $val));
}
var_dump($ar);
```

Comment: Or maybe not, this didnt give me the values only, but the keys aswell :-(

Comment: @RasmusBidstrup added an option stripping keys.

Comment: Its funny when i get the result, the big numbers has changed: [[2147483647,1],[2147483647,1],[2147483647,1],[2147483647,1]] Is that because of the BIT32?

Comment: @RasmusBidstrup Yes, you're hitting the 32-bit int limit, which is why AbraCadaver made the comment to your original post about being on a 64-bit system.